# MySQL Join Query confuse

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 table as below:

1. product (product_id, product_desc)
2. product_sales_branch_a (product_id, qty)
3. product_sales_branch_b (product_id, qty)

I use join product & product_sales_branch_a to get the sales qty using the following script:

```
select A.product_desc, sum(B.qty) from product A 
join product_sales_branch_a B on B.product_id = A.product_id
where A.product_id = 'ABC*'
```

Result:

```
product_desc | sum(B.qty)    
1234         | 16
```

The result returns correctly.

Then, I use join product & product_sales_branch_b to get the sales qty using the following script:

```
select A.product_desc, sum(C.qty) from product A 
join product_sales_branch_b C on C.product_id = A.product_id 
where A.product_id = 'ABC'
```

Result:

```
product_desc | sum(C.qty)
1234         | 20
```

The result also returns correctly.

But now, i'm trying to join the 3 table by the following script:

```
select A.product_desc, sum(B.qty), sum(C.qty) from product A 
join product_sales_branch_a B on B.product_id = A.product_id 
join product_sales_branch_b C on C.product_id = A.product_id 
where A.product_id = 'ABC'
```

Result:

```
product_desc | sum(B.qty) | sum(C.qty)
1234         | 288        | 280
```

Which is not the result that i expected for.

Anything wrong on my sql query?

Comment: Are you doing this :-  `SELECT t1.col, t3.col FROM table1 join table2 ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey
                                  join table3 ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
`

Comment: in the first query product_id is 'ABC*' ?

Comment: can you setup some sample data in the http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: 'ABC*' is actually my typo there. The 1 use correctly is 'ABC'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with sub-selects in this case:

```
select A.product_desc,
       (select sum(B.qty) from product_sales_branch_a B where B.product_id = A.product_id),
       (select sum(C.qty) from product_sales_branch_b C where C.product_id = A.product_id) 
from product A 
where A.product_id = 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you join the third table, there is no relation between the second and third table. Therefore, if the join of tables 1 and 2 returns m rows, and join of 1 and 3 returns n rows, you will get m * n rows as output. That is why your sum is much larger than expected.

[Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db40c/2)

One way to work around this is to use `count distinct`, if you are very sure that there are no repeated values for `qty`. However, this is not likely in real data, so you should consider going with the subquery approach as suggested by @jarlh above:

```
select A.product_desc as desc,
   (select sum(B.qty) from product_sales_branch_a B where B.product_id = A.product_id and A.product_id = 'ABC') as bqty,
   (select sum(C.qty) from product_sales_branch_b C where C.product_id = A.product_id  and A.product_id = 'ABC') as cqty
from product A
```